# Is there any technique to explore the relevance of interaction terms to a regression before adding to the model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-strategies, interaction

As usually, I've got an independent ($y$) and many dependent ($x_{1}, ..., x_{k}$) variables. I'd like to add interaction terms to my linear regression, but the vast number of variables makes it really time-consuming. Therefore, I'm looking for a technique to explore whether the introduced interaction term is relevant to my regression model or not.

For example, when I'd like to add a quadratic term to my regression model, I run an $x,y$ scatter plot. If the distribution of the dependent variable looks like quadratic at first sight, the quadratic variable got the chance being significant in the regression, too. Is there any thumb-rule like this out there for introducing new interaction terms to my regression?

I also inquired correlation matrices. I found in some cases that $corr(y,x_{i})\approx 0,05$ and $corr(y,x_{j})\approx -0,02$, but $corr(y,x_{i}x_{j})\approx 0,45$.  Is the best method finding significant interaction terms to try out different variable combinations with brute-force?

I will be grateful if you can send me this information.

Comment: You can automate the searching process with most statistical software.  While this method can be controversial, with this process, you could set up all the interactions and have the software loop over the interactions and test them one by one.  Ones that appear significant could all be entered together into the model to determine if they remain significant when entered among the other significant interactions.  Keep only the ones that continue to remains statistically significant.

Of course, I prefer to be guided by theory.  Only enter those interactions which are plausible in theory.

Comment: 3209Cigs answer is pretty good. Basically, they're saying to try one of two approaches to testing interactions: 1) use a "shotgun" approach that is programming and CPU intensive that explores all possible combinations of 2-way, 3-way or higher interactions or 2) use SME and theory to guide the selection. There is a third way that is more parsimonious than the first approach and less reliant on SME than the second. A third way is to explore interactions only among a subset of the most strongly predictive independent variables.

Comment: Use lasso variable selection. Precalculate the interactions first and let lasso tell you which ones are useful. Look at glmnet if you are using R.

Comment: Another method to try is variance inflation factor (VIF).

Comment: @DJohnson, Can you please provide some reference for these approaches, particularly in R